# Want only two decimal value in percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using below query to generate the percentage in a new column but I want only two decimal places.

```
    SELECT 
count( *) TestCount
,count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) TestPassedCount
,count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) / count(*) ThePercentage
,asset 
 FROM Table_Name
 group by asset
```

Current Output:

```
             TestCount  TestPassedCount    Percentage   Asset
                 18             7          0.388888889  DB2MOTIV:DBMOTIVA@mxemch010405ads.mx.hsbc
```

Required Output:

```
             TestCount  TestPassedCount    Percentage   Asset
                 18             7              38.89    DB2MOTIV:DBMOTIVA@mxemch010405ads.mx.hsbc
```

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: You can't possibly be getting 0.38888889 from the code posted. You have count / count which is two integers so you would get an integer result.

Comment: You can use CAST(<field or operation> AS DECIMAL(10,2)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Round(  count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) / count(*) * 100 , 2) ThePercentage
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is what you want to achieve, just multiply your result with 100 and add `round` function:

```
SELECT 
 count( *) TestCount
 ,count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) TestPassedCount
 ,round((count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) / count(*)) * 100,2) ThePercentage
 ,asset 
FROM 
 Table_Name
group by 
 asset
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ROUND method

```
 SELECT 
        count( *) TestCount
        ,count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) TestPassedCount
        ,ROUND((count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) / count(*))*100,2) ThePercentage
        ,asset 
         FROM Table_Name
         group by asset
```